# Export to PDF/Word/Excel (As Is)

Tags: c#, pdf, export

Is there some component/api/method available that will allow me to export a CURRENT PAGE (aspx/html) to PDF while also heeding the CSS rules of the page?

I have a report I generate with 3 columns, tables and plenty of CSS, but when I export to Excel, PDF, HTML - I end up with a black and white result, that needs to then have the CSS re-applied in code which is cumbersome.

> NB*. Obviously in my mind this sounds improbable given that the
>   component/api/method would need to interpret HTML & CSS.

Thanks

Comment: maybe? http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: Yeah I had a look at that as well - but again, that by calling a page. I guess I could do that by customizing it to take arguments via QueryString. Will give it another look

Comment: We do exports to pdf, etc, with SSRS. I've gone down that road with trying to build HTML reports and while they work great for an HTML rendering.. the frustration in getting that stuff to go along with PDF generation is just above having your bum belt sanded. If SSRS is ever an option, you might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Expected Behavior, and we've developed an API called DocRaptor that converts HTML to PDF and Excel format. We use Prince XML for PDF generation, and our output is much higher quality than similar APIs.

It sounds like your main concern is correct interpretation of HTML and CSS, and DocRaptor has extensive CSS support. We use HTTP POST requests for document generation, and DocRaptor can be used with C# (as well as many other languages)

Here's a link to our C# coding example:

[DocRaptor C# example](http://docraptor.com/documentation/examples_csharp)

And a link to DocRaptor's home page:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)